# Unique has_many through combination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, unique, has-many-through

I just have this simple setup:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :players
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :teams, -> { uniq }, through: :players
end
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :team_id }
end
```

With this I can create multiple Teams with the same user combination by calling this twice:

```
Team.create(user_ids: ["1","2"])
```

How to make sure that there is not already another team with these users?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make sure each team has a unique combination of users?

Comment: Yes, if there already is a team with user1 and user2 i can't create a new team with this combination.

Comment: So would you want the following to work? `Team.create(user_ids: ["1","2"]); create(user_ids: ["1","2","3"])` Sorry, I am just trying to understand what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want users to be able to join multiple teams?

Comment: For sure, a user can be member of multiple teams.
This should be possible: Team.create(user_ids: ["1","2"]); create(user_ids: ["1","3"])
and this: Team.create(user_ids: ["1","2"]); create(user_ids: ["1","2","3"])
but not this: Team.create(user_ids: ["1","2"]); create(user_ids: ["1","2"])